# EF Core navigation 'Department.SubDepartments' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it

Tags: ef-core-6.0

I have a simple model in which a `Company` can have `Departments` and a `Department` has `SubDepartments`, and I'm trying to configure with nested `OwnsMany` as follows:

```cs
public class CompanyTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> companyBuilder) 
    {
        companyBuilder.Navigation(company => company.Departments).Metadata.SetField("_departments");
        companyBuilder.Navigation(company => company.Departments).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        companyBuilder.OwnsMany(company => company.Departments, departmentsBuilder => {
            departmentsBuilder.Property(department => department.Name).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
            departmentsBuilder.Property(department => department.SubDepartments).IsRequired();
            departmentsBuilder.Navigation(department => department.SubDepartments).Metadata.SetField("_subDepartments");
            departmentsBuilder.Navigation(department => department.SubDepartments).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        });
    }
}
```

I get the following exception about `Department.SubDepartments` - but I already added that:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Navigation 'Department.SubDepartments' was not found. Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.

Definitely missing something, not able to figure out what.

If I remove everything relating to `SubDepartment` (last 3 lines from the above configuration, and `SubDepartment` navigation prop from `Department`), things are working fine.

As of now, I feel, based on my discussion with my domain experts, that `Department` is totally dependent on company, so I have configured with `OwnsMany`. And I also intend to make `SubDepartment` owned by `Department`, making that a nested one. But just introducing `SubDepartment` itself is causing that exception.

What am I missing?

The domain classes look as follows:

```cs
public class Company : BaseEntity<long>, IAggregateRoot
{
    private Company() { }

    public Company(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; } = default!;

    private readonly List<Department> _departments = new List<Department>();
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Department> Departments => _departments.AsReadOnly();
}

public class Department
{
    public Department(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private readonly List<SubDepartment> _subDepartments = new List<SubDepartment>();

    public string Name { get; private init; } = default!;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<SubDepartment> SubDepartments => _subDepartments.AsReadOnly();
}

public class SubDepartment
{
    public SubDepartment(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private init; } = default!;
}
```

I am testing it as follows.

```cs
public static void TestCompany()
{
    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CompanyContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MeWurkCompanyDept").Options;

    using (var companyContext = new CompanyContext(dbContextOptions))
        companyContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
}
```

### Update

As of now, I got it work with the following.

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> companyBuilder)
{
    companyBuilder.Navigation(company => company.Departments).Metadata.SetField("_departments");
    companyBuilder.Navigation(company => company.Departments).UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    companyBuilder.OwnsMany(company => company.Departments, departmentsBuilder =>
    {
        departmentsBuilder.Property(department => department.Name).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
        departmentsBuilder.OwnsMany(department => department.SubDepartments, subDepartment =>
        {

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not intended to be an answer, but I will share my similar case and solution.

I got the same message

> Please add the navigation to the entity type before configuring it.

when running

```
dotnet ef migrations add SomeNameHere
```

The message was pointing out to a line in DbContextModelSnapshot:

```
modelBuilder.Entity("TheEntity", b =>
            {
                b.Navigation("TheNavigationProperty");
            });
```

I **removed that line** and ran the command again, then it worked.

It is interesting that the removed line was regenerated. I think the error started due to an automatic merge in repository.

Maybe it can help someone else.

Comment: This happens when you have several add/remove actions and one of them failed. Now, if you just delete the last migration by deleting the *.cs file, the stack of migration steps and the snapshot are out of sync.

It's better to revoke a migration using the tool instead of just deleting the file. 

But manipulating the snapshot seems fine, too, if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put these lines in the correct order like following:

```
    builder.Entity<Order>().HasOne(typeof(ApplicationUser), "ForStoreUser").WithMany().HasForeignKey("ForStoreUserId").IsRequired();
    builder.Entity<Order>().Navigation(d => d.ForStoreUser).AutoInclude(true);
```